# Automatic memoisation with support for recursive function

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, memoization

The blog post [Automatic Memoization in c++0x](http://slackito.com/2011/03/17/automatic-memoization-in-cplusplus0x/) provides an function for producing a memoized version of an existing function. The blog post and the associated code have been discussed previously on stackoverflow (e.g. [What does this C++11 code do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353141/what-does-this-c11-code-do)), however, none of these solutions is able to provide a fully universal memoizer which is able to correctly memoize recursive functions as well.

Sure, there is the trick of changing the recursive call by using something like this (assuming we have a memoizer such as the one presented in the blog post called `memoize` already in place):

```c++
std::function<int (int)> f;
int fib(int n) {
  if  (n < 2) return n;
  return f(n-1) + f(n-2);
}

int main(void) {
  f = memoize(std::function<int (int)>(fib));
}
```

But this feels more like a workaround than a proper solution because we still need access to the function which we want to memoize. A proper solution should be able to fully memoize any function including the ones which are defined in some library. However, producing such a solution, so it seems, is beyond my reach (assuming it is possible), therefore I'm asking:

> Is a truly universal memoise function possible?
>   *How* can one achieve such a feat?

And if this is not possible, is there at least a way to generalise the above approach. Something along the lines of (does not compile and is not valid C++):

```c++
int fib(int n){
  if  (n < 2) return n;
  return this_func(n-1) + this_func(n-2);
}
```

Where `this_func` is something which is similar to the `this` pointer of a class but for a function. [**Edit:** This would probably still suffer from the problem that the `this_func` pointer would point to `fib` instead of the memoized `fib`]

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this today, particularly with pre-compiled libraries.  My first guess at a way to add memoization after the fact would be to use the linker to substitute the relocations of fib() with a memoized_fib() wrapper function.  However I don't know the details of the compile and link phases to know whether the internal recursion would even be available during the link phase for substitution.  Oh, and I don't know of a linker that will do that kind of substitution either.

Comment: If you want the recursive calls to use the same cache, I think you need to somehow share the cache between them. That is, either use a `static` (better, but yet slower: `thread_local`) cache or pass the cache as an additional argument. Either way requires a modification of `fib`. (There's [an example on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_combinator#Explanation_for_imperative_programmers) that uses the latter technique, passing the cache via the memoized version of the function as an argument.)

Answer (score 2):

As the cache needs to be shared across function calls, you'd either have to pass it as an argument, or share it otherwise. One way to share it is using a function object:

```
struct fib
{
    std::map<std::tuple<int>, int> cache;

    int operator()(int n)
    {
        if(n < 2) return n;

        auto memoize = [this](int p)
        {
            auto i = cache.find(p);
            if(i == cache.end()) i = cache.insert({p, (*this)(p)}).first;
            return i->second;
        };

        return memoize(n-1) + memoize(n-2);
    }
};
```

Where you can factor out the `memoize` part.

There's also a trick with temporary lifetime to pass the memoized function as an argument; something like this:

```
struct recurse // possibly a class template
{
    std::function<int(int, recurse const&)> f; // possibly `mutable`

    template<class T>
    recurse(T&& p) : f( memoize(decltype(f){p}) )
    {}

    int operator()(int x) const
    {
        return f(x, *this);
    }
};

int fib(int n, recurse const& f);

int fib(int n, recurse const& f = {fib})
{
    if(n < 2) return n;
    return f(n-1) + f(n-2); // or `fib(n-1, f) + fib(n-2, f)`
}
```

Yet, this requires a change of `memoize`, as the `recurse const&` cannot (and shouldn't) be part of the internal `map`.

<sub>N.B. those `const&` could also be `&&` for lifetime extension, yet, that might be confusing due to move semantics</sub>

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is not possible while staying within the bounds of defined behavior, because there's no way to abstract out the recursive call.  In fact, I can't think of anything significantly better than the global variable version that you provided.

One obvious idea to provide an abstraction point more robust than a global variable would be to add the function to recurse on as a first argument:

```
int fib(std::function<int (int)> rec, int n)
{
    if (n < 2) return n;
    return rec(n - 1) + rec(n - 2);
}
```

Then, you could modify your memoize function to pass the memoized version into the first argument, and things should just work.  This trick is often used to accomplish the same goal in (unityped/untyped) functional languages like scheme.

However, this sort of trick relies on something called the ["Y combinator"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y_combinator) which I think can't exist in C++ as it has an infinite type.

Comment: you're right, the point of my answer is that it doesn't work as there's no way to type it without going outside the standard, since C++ has no support for recursive types

Answer (score 0):

Following may help, but it is still a hack, and it is ugly... :

```
int fib(void* f, int n)
{
  if (n < 2) return n;
  auto this_func = *reinterpret_cast<std::function<int (void*, int)>*>(f);
  return this_func(f, n - 1) + this_func(f, n - 2);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::function<int (void*, int n)> fib1 = &fib;
    std::cout << fib1(reinterpret_cast<void*>(&fib1), 5) << std::endl;

    auto f = memoize(fib1);
    std::cout << f(reinterpret_cast<void*>(&f), 5) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I use `void*` since the correct signature is recursive :-/

Comment: The `void*` is also a problem in C, where IIRC `struct`s are used that contain the function pointer as a member. Something like `struct recursive_fun { using f = int(recursive_fun, int); f* m; };` (Of course you can add `operator()` in C++)

Comment: Actually, then it could be simplified by just using a function object with the cache as a data member ;)